# Edit SQL records using visual editor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I can **Edit/Select** records or Design table using **visual editor** in MSSQL Management Studio. However it is possible if I use local server (or local database), when I connect to remote server I have no such options.

From another hand, I saw such options from my friend's computer. What module allows to enable visual editing mode?

[image]

Comment: What version of management studio are you using, and what version is the database you want to edit the rows on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not setting which disable or enable visual editing mode at all. Though you can change the value of "Edit top  Rows".
You should check for privileges you own. Verify your friend's has login using same credentials which you are trying.

Comment: Thanks, but credentials - the same